# Word that means "to change color"?

Tags: word-request

I checked the Reverso Dictionary but found [nothing](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-synonyms/to%20change%20color).
Searching for [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/change) for change didn't yield any results, either.

Any suggestions?

Example sentence:

> The sky ___ from red to maroon and from maroon to black.

Comment: It's in the synonym list. "The sky **turned** from red to maroon and from maroon to black."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Turn](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turn)*** is the verb commonly used to indicate a change in state, conditions of someone or something:

> - [ L, I or T usually + adv/prep ] to (cause to) become, change into, or come to be something:
>
>   - *The weather has suddenly turned cold.*
>   - *When I refused to pay, he turned nasty.*
>   - *She turned pale and started to shiver.*
>   - ***By the end of September, the leaves have started to turn (= become brown).***

Cambridge Dictionary

- [Russian river turned red](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/09/12/world/russia-red-river-siberia/) by metallurgical waste, Norilsk Nickel says.

From: CNN.com

Answer (score 1):

One of the meanings of the expression ["to change into something"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/change+into) is *to transform from one state to some other*. In your sentence, it's its color that the sun changes (in the way how it's perceived by the observers) from red into maroon.

Answer (score 0):

The sky *moved* from red to maroon and from maroon to black.

The sky *transitioned* from red to maroon and from maroon to black.

The sky *transformed* from red to maroon and from maroon to black.

The sky *faded* from red to maroon and from maroon to black.(normally darker)

The sky *faded* from red to maroon and from maroon to black.

The sky *brightened* from red to maroon and from maroon to black. (normally lighter)

The sky *went* from red to maroon and from maroon to black.